# Eclipselink with criteria - (isEmpty for subquery with wrong result)

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

I am working with EclipsLink and I got this issue.

The JPQL bellow bring me only one result, that is the correct result:

`select distinct c from Car c join c.person p where p.dogs is empty`.

The result is:
Car name: Yellow Submarine

_

But when I create the Criteria bellow:

`CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Car> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Car.class);
    Root<Car> mainRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Car.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(mainRoot);
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
    Join<Person, Car> join = mainRoot.join("person", JoinType.INNER);
    // Is this right?
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.isEmpty(join.get("dogs").as(List.class))));`

The wrong result is given:Car name: Black Horse, Car name: White Thunder, Car name: Herbie, Car name: Yellow Submarine

It brings all the data from the database. Am I missing anything?

The same criteria above works fine for Hibernate. =/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look like it is a bug. =/

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368752/

Thanks. [=

Answer (score 0):

What is the SQL generated?

Try just,

```
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.isEmpty(join.<Collection>get("dogs"));
```

Also try the latest release.